# Add KivyMD Expansion Panel inside RecyleView kivy

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

anyone can help me about how to add KivyMD Expansion Panel in RecycleView kivy? Because I have issue with slow perfomance while add MDExpansionPanel with "add_widget" on kivy (run in old android).

Then i have idea to put Expansion into RecycleView, but the expansionpanel can't open with true index.

fyi, i have make custom expansion.py file

**expansion.py**

```
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.list import (IRightBody, ILeftBody, TwoLineAvatarIconListItem)
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox

Builder.load_string(
    """
#:import images_path kivymd.images_path
#:import md_icons kivymd.icon_definitions.md_icons
<CustomExpansionPanel>
    text: root.title
    secondary_text: root.desc
    _no_ripple_effect: True

    IconRightSampleWidget:
        id: check
        disabled_color: [.2, .3, .6, .9]
        disabled: True

    ChevronRight:
        id: chevron
        icon: 'chevron-right'
        disabled: True

        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: self.angle
                axis: (0, 0, 1)
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix

<CustomMDExpansionPanel>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: dp(68)
    padding:dp(0)

    BoxLayout:
        id: box_item
        size_hint_y: None
        height: root.height
        orientation: 'vertical'

        CustomExpansionPanel:
            id: item_anim
            title: root.title
            desc: root.desc
            on_press: root.check_open_box(self)
"""
)


class IconRightSampleWidget(ILeftBody, MDCheckbox):
    pass


class ChevronRight(IRightBody, MDIconButton):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)


class CustomExpansionPanel(TwoLineAvatarIconListItem):
    title = StringProperty()
    desc = StringProperty()


class CustomMDExpansionPanel(BoxLayout):
    content = ObjectProperty()
    title = StringProperty()
    desc = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomMDExpansionPanel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type("on_open")
        self.register_event_type("on_close")

    def on_open(self, *args):
        pass

    def on_close(self, *args):
        pass

    def check_open_box(self, instance,CloseAll=False):
        press_current_item = False
        for box in self.parent.children:
            if isinstance(box, CustomMDExpansionPanel):
                if len(box.ids.box_item.children) == 2:
                    if instance is box.ids.item_anim:
                        press_current_item = True
                    box.ids.box_item.remove_widget(box.ids.box_item.children[0])
                    chevron = box.ids.box_item.children[0].ids.chevron
                    self.anim_chevron_up(chevron)
                    self.anim_resize_close(box)
                    self.dispatch("on_close")
                    break

        if not press_current_item and not CloseAll:
            self.anim_chevron_down()
    
    def anim_chevron_down(self):
        chevron = self.ids.item_anim.ids.chevron
        angle = -90
        Animation(angle=angle, d=0.2).start(chevron)
        self.anim_resize_open_item()
        self.dispatch("on_open")

    def anim_chevron_up(self, instance):
        angle = 0
        Animation(angle=angle, d=0.2).start(instance)

    def anim_resize_close(self, box):
        Animation(height=dp(68), d=0.1, t="in_cubic").start(box)

    def anim_resize_open_item(self, *args):
        self.content.name_item = self.title
        anim = Animation(
            height=self.content.height + dp(70), d=0.2, t="in_cubic"
        )
        anim.bind(on_complete=self.add_content)
        anim.start(self)

    def add_content(self, *args):
        if self.content and len(self.ids.box_item.children) == 1:
            self.ids.box_item.add_widget(self.content)
```

**main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp as App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from expansion import CustomMDExpansionPanel
from time import time
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string(
    """
<ListScreen>:
    recycle_view: recycle_view
    RecycleView:
        id: recycle_view
        size_hint: 1, 0.9
        viewclass: "CustomMDExpansionPanel"
        RecycleGridLayout:
            id: items_box
            cols:1
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            height:self.minimum_height
"""
)
class Container(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Container,self).__init__()
class ListScreen(Screen):

    recycle_view = ObjectProperty(None)
    items_box = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_enter(self):
        start = time()
        container = []
        for i in range(0,50):
            container.append(Container(item='strrr'+str(i), index=i))
            self.recycle_view.data.append(
                {
                    'content':container[i],
                    'title':'title'+str(i), 
                    'desc':'desc'+str(i)
                }
            )
    def on_leave(self):
        self.recycle_view.data = []

class ListApp(App):

    sm = ScreenManager()
    screens = {}

    def build(self):
        self.__create_screens()
        ListApp.sm.add_widget(ListApp.screens['list1'])
        return ListApp.sm

    def __create_screens(self):
        ListApp.screens['list1'] = ListScreen(name='list1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ListApp().run()
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding , if you are trying to add your **expansion panel** inside the **RecycleView**.

Here is an example code of how to do that

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel, MDExpansionPanelThreeLine
from kivymd import images_path

KV = """
<Content>
    adaptive_height: True

    TwoLineIconListItem:
        text: "(050)-123-45-67"
        secondary_text: "Mobile"


RecycleView:

    MDGridLayout:
        id: box
        cols: 1
        adaptive_height: True
"""


class Content(MDBoxLayout):
    """Custom content."""


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.root.ids.box.add_widget(
                MDExpansionPanel(
                    icon=f"{images_path}kivymd.png",
                    content=Content(),
                    panel_cls=MDExpansionPanelThreeLine(
                        text="Text",
                        secondary_text="Secondary text",
                        tertiary_text="Tertiary text",
                    ),
                )
            )


Test().run()
```

**Please Refer Documentations Before Asking Questions :) As It Solves 90 % Of Your Problems <3**

Also Edit Your Question And Specify Your Problem Clearly :)

Comment: I know is not directly related to the question, but is there to add a clickable icon to the panel, like an icon that when clicked call's a function without triggering the expansion of the panel itself, like an icon next to the word "text" , that response to a click event.